# Entity Framework check current value before update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a repository for CRUD operations. Basically if we want to do any of the read/write operations we can do something like

```
    using (MemberRepo mRepo = new MemberRepo())
    {
         mRepo.UpdateEntity(member);
         mRepo.Save();
    }
```

What I need to know however is if it is possible to know a certain column value in the database before we update it? For example if there is a field in the member table called Status and I want to know the current existing status of that member before I update it with some other value?

Thanks.

Comment: retrieve the existing value check it and then update.

Comment: Yeah we can do that but I was thinking that in SQL Server when we write triggers on an update we have a handle on an object (table) called deleted which has the values before the update happened. I was thinking we have something like that in EF where we don't have to actually read the whole obj again

Comment: but as per i know there are no support for triggers in EF.

Comment: Not trigger support but something along the lines on what I am trying to do here.

Comment: ORM tools doesn't support that, if needed you can create a custom repository patter for that.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will let you set the creation date of any entity that has this column/attribute. It can work as a trigger in some cases.

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreationDate") != null))
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entry.Property("CreationDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```